# Is there a way to check if a function returns one from two given numbers in phpunit?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

In `phpunit`, using `assertEquals` we can check whether a function returns a specific value. Is there a way we can check whether a function returns one of the two(or more) values?

Comment: We need a bit more information, what determines the value? If you pass in the same arguments, do you get the same value? Or is it due to a side effect like reading a file?

Comment: @Schwern Correct, this is due to side effect like reading a file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but how you do it depends on the details.

If it's a case where it should be roughly, but not exactly, a number `assertEqualsWithDelta()`. For example, if the result should be 1 but there's floating point error: `assertEqualsWithDelta(1.0, result, 0.0001)`

If you'll get one value with one set of arguments, but a different value with another set of arguments, you'd test both sets of arguments. `assertEquals(true, function(value_for_which_its_true))` and `assertEquals(false, function(value_for_which_its_false))`.

If the outcome is hard to determine because of a side effect, you need to control that side effect. For example, if your function reads from a file you need to control the contents of that file. Usually this is done by writing a temp file and using that.

```
$temp = tmpfile();
fwrite($temp, "known test data");
$temp_path = stream_get_meta_data($tmpfile)['uri']
```

Exactly how you get your code to use that temp file depends on how your code is written. This often reveals inflexible designs like hard-coded filenames. You may have to change the design of your function to accept a file path or filehandle, or if you're using objects, to read the it from the object. You may have to split a large function that does too many things into a set of smaller functions which each do one thing.